# I'm trying to link Node.js+Webpack+MySQL, but it's stuck in fs module. Help me

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, webpack

I tried to run the program by linking MySQL and Node.js, but fs cannot be loaded due to the following errors.

**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'**

By the way, adding **target:'node'**, causes a **global is not defined** error.

and add **node {fs:'empty'}**, causes a **createConnection is not a function** error.

What should I do now

> **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    return {
        mode: 'production',
        entry: {
            index : path.join(__dirname, 'src' ,'index.ts'),
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
            filename: 'game.js',
            library: 'game',
            libraryTarget: 'umd'
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
            modules: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),"node_modules"
            ]
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test : /\.ts$/,
                    use: [{ loader: 'ts-loader'}]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

> **mysql function**

```
function get_connection():void {
    console.log("mysql : ",mysql)
    console.log("mysql.createConnection", mysql.createConnection)

    connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "host",
        user: "user",
        password: "pass",
        database: "database"
    }).then(conn => {
        console.log('promise-mysql createConnection.');
        connection = conn;
        return conn;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("promise fail:",err)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're keen to use webpack to bundle for node server code, you shouldn't bundle node_nodules by using this helper `webpack-node-externals`. So try more with these options:

```
 var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

 target: 'node',
 externals: [
   nodeExternals(),
 ],
 node: {
   fs: "empty",
 }
```